# Making loop more efficient

Tags: java, java-8

So I have an arrayList of msgs, each is classified as either `static` or `dynamic`
I create a vessel or find a vessel object (from an arrayList of vessels) and add the information to the vessel depending on msg type.

```
 VesselS vessels = new VesselS(); 
        msgs.forEach(msg -> { 
            if (msg instanceof DynamicDataReport) {
                DynamicDataReport dynamicDataReport = (DynamicDataReport) msg;
                Vessel vessel = new Vessel(msg.getSourceMmsi().getMMSI());
                Coordinate coord = new Coordinate(dynamicDataReport.getLongitude(),dynamicDataReport.getLatitude()); 
                int index = vessels.index(vessel); 
                if(index < 0) { //if vessel is not present in vessels
                    vessel.addCoor(coord);
                    vessels.addVessel(vessel);
                }
                else{ //if vessel is already in vessels 
                    vessels.getVessels().get(index).addCoor(coord);
                }
            }
```

This is the first part, I thought using an index variable might be easier than searching for the index twice (in the next section of code), but it didn't seem to effect the run time.

```
else if (msg instanceof StaticDataReport) {
                StaticDataReport staticDataReport = (StaticDataReport) msg;
                Vessel vessel = new Vessel(msg.getSourceMmsi().getMMSI());
                String shipName = staticDataReport.getShipName(); 
                String callSign = staticDataReport.getCallsign(); 
                if(!vessels.contains(vessel)) { //if vessel is not present in vessels
                    vessel.addname(shipName);
                    vessel.setCallSign(callSign);
                    vessels.addVessel(vessel);
                }
                else{ //if vessel is already in vessels 
                    vessels.getVessels().get(vessels.index(vessel)).addname(shipName);
                }
            }
            });
```

First time working with a lot of information and I need to minimize runtime. Would it be worth looking into storing vessels in trees opposed to lists ? is there redundancy in my code that I can cut down on ? 
 My `contains` and `index` methods are just loops.

```
public boolean contains(Vessel vessel){ 
    for(int i= 0; i<Vessels.size(); i++){
        if(Vessels.get(i).getMMSI() == vessel.getMMSI()){
            return true; 
        }
    }
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: What is your equals method in Vessels?

Comment: If it comes to design, you better first eliminate the `instanceof` it is very *un-object oriented*.

Comment: the code is really confusing. the loop in contains calls static method Vessels.size() but it should be instance method

Comment: also, if you're using java 8 stream api, why you revert to old for loop in the contains method? why you use both index and contains to determine if a vessel exists in the collection?\

Comment: @CommuSoft unfortunately the instanceof is due to the decoder I'm using and the hierarchy it leaves msgs in.

Comment: @sharonbn contains method is in the vessels class that has an arraylist of vessels. Would using new for loop be more efficient ?, I also explained that I tried index in the first part thinking it might effect run time(opposed to using contains).

Comment: Let us start with, how big is your list? Depending on that we can try look at a solution

Comment: using stream().filter(v -> v.getMMSI() == vessel.getMMSI()) is more efficient and be sure you want to use == and not equals()

Comment: @aksappy the hope is to read as many as possible, currently my data set is 1.3 million and it takes 12 seconds total, 6 seconds decoding and 6 seconds running this loop.

Comment: Cool. Can i assume that your MMSI is unique for every Vessel?

Comment: @aksappy yeah, a vessel is comprised of a mmsi, callsign, ArrayList <String> names, ArrayList <String> AIS  and ArrayList <Coordinate> coordinates

Comment: If it is unique, you can remove the lengthy contains and index methods by a map, cant you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your list is modifiable during program execution and if your MMSI code is unique, use a HashMap (faster) or a TreeHashMap with key as MMSI and value as Vessel. Then instead of contains method, use something like below

```
Vessel vessel = map.get(tempVesse.getMMSI());
if(null!=vessel)
    //do this
else
    // do that
```

You can use the map.contains() in treehashmap which is using binary search.
Cons for doing this - you have to manage a map instead of a list

Or else, you can use `Collections.binarySearch` directly to search for the required object, which is ought to be faster in theory at least (see an example [here](http://java2novice.com/java-collections-and-util/collections/binary-search/)). You will have to sort the object list before doing the search operation and that will be an overhead atleast for once, which is the con for this approach

I have not seen any visible impacts on performance from your code otherwise.

And it also includes your design level decision to do an in memory search instead of a DB or something of that sort. A list of 1.3 million objects is a bit heavy, if you ask me.